# graphics in c and c++

Tags: c++, c, bgi

In turbo c 3.2 I am getting

> Divide error

and in code blocks IDE I getting error that

> initgraph() and closegraph() are refrence at compile time. (I added graphics header and library file in folder of codeblocks).Please give me solution?

the code i written is

```
#include<graphics.h>
int main()
{
   int a=10,ab;
   initgraph(&a,&ab,"C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");
   circle(100,200,20);
   closegraph();
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're trying to do and what it wrong. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And you should copy and paste error messages exactly.

Comment: Turbo C is ancient history by now. So is the `"graphics.h"` header file and the library. What you learn from using them will have no (or very little) practical bearing on your life later as a programmer.

Comment: Turbo C was discontinued ages ago. Do yourself a favor and use something else.

Comment: I have colleagues that are younger than that compiler. Please get a book or teacher that teaches this centuries' programming.

Comment: "_I uploaded the picture of error on turbo C_" **Don't** post pictures of errors: **copy-paste** them.

Comment: @Klutt turbo C discontinued but no IDE supporting graphics. h header file and to manually include it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BGI in computer graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322352/bgi-in-computer-graphics)

Comment: @david I seen that but still getting error and now saying divide error

Comment: @kd vote retracted and possible answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the backslash issue in the path, it's *extremely* unlikely that you are using a 3270 compatible display.  Why don't you pass in the address of `a` with `a=0`.  `ab` must be set to a requested mode unless you set the driver to `autodetect`, which will then select the highest available mode.  See [here](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/initgraph.html).

Comment: Thanks it works now

Answer (score 0):

The path string should be "C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI" (note the double backslashes instead of single backslashes)
I hope this solves the problem. I can't see any other error in code.

Comment: Still getting error of "divide error"

Comment: Made sure that C:\TURBOC3\BGI is the address of EGAVGA.BGI file ?

Comment: Yes sure there contains EGAVGA.BGI file at that address